# Is there a way to see the date of when webforms were opened and closed?

Tags: webforms

I'm using Drupal 9 and would like to know when a webform was closed to check that we haven't had a security breach and received submissions after the form was closed.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not, Webforms are config and config elements don't store revision information. If you have the database logging module enabled, you might find a DB log entry though when a webform config was saved (see `/admin/reports/dblog`). But this log doesn't say which field (or if any field at all) has been changed, it just means "the save button was clicked".

(And if you have a security breach, this info would be untrustworthy anyways, because all those logs can be manipulated programmatically from within Drupal too.)